# Summation of multiple map layers?

Tags: google-earth-engine, precipitation, summarizing

What I am trying to do is to take a specific range of time (summer) over multiple years and then sum the total amount of precipitation onto a final layer.

This is the code I am working with

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('IDAHO_EPSCOR/GRIDMET')

var precip = dataset.select('pr');
var precipVIS = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 10.0,
  palette: ['d8d8d8', '4addff', '5affa3', 'f2ff89', 'ff725c'],
};
Map.setCenter(-86.356, 44.686, 9);

Map.addLayer(
    precip.filterDate("2014-06-15", "2014-07-15"), precipVIS,
    '2014');
Map.addLayer(
    precip.filterDate("2015-06-15", "2015-07-15"), precipVIS,
    '2015');
```

Now I am looking for the last part where I sum the results of the two map layers '2014' & '2015'.

Answer (score 1):

To do this by year, you can reduce the timeframe of each individual year using `ee.Reducer.sum()` and then add the two years together:

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('IDAHO_EPSCOR/GRIDMET');

var precip = dataset.select('pr');
var precipVIS = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 10.0,
  palette: ['d8d8d8', '4addff', '5affa3', 'f2ff89', 'ff725c'],
};
Map.setCenter(-86.356, 44.686, 9);

Map.addLayer(
    precip.filterDate("2014-06-15", "2014-07-15"), precipVIS,
    '2014');
Map.addLayer(
    precip.filterDate("2015-06-15", "2015-07-15"), precipVIS,
    '2015');

var precip2014 = precip.filterDate("2014-06-15", "2014-07-15");
var precip2015 = precip.filterDate("2015-06-15", "2015-07-15");

var total2014 = precip2014.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum());
var total2015 = precip2015.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum());

var final = total2014.add(total2015);
Map.addLayer(final, precipVIS,
    'total');
```

Comment: Something is wrong with the reducer function when it comes to this data. 

Add that code to what I wrote and then compare the layers - there are pockets that show up in the 2014 layer that are not found in the summed layer. 

Are there other functions that would better serve to sum the layers?

Comment: That's weird; when I run the complete code (see updated answer) there aren't any holes in the summed layer (`final`).

Comment: It's not that there are "holes" necessarily. But if you look at each year individually, note where you see isolated areas of heavy red.

Then look at the final layer - those spots don't show up in the summed layer. 

For example, look at Kingsley in 2014 and then look at it on the "summed" model (using the parameters for the final model "min: 100 max: 200"

And that's my other question: why is the minimum value output for the final layer 100+? The whole layer is entirely red, which means that the value is 100+ everywhere?

Comment: Ah I see what you're talking about now. There are several layers within each season (e.g. `precip2014`) so summing across the year racks up values to a quite high value when you get to the point of summing across years. For example use `Map.addLayer(total2014, precipVIS, 'total2014');` and you'll see that there is lots of precip over the season (far more than the default visualization of the first layer in `precip2014`).

Comment: Right, i see that now. I'm trying to get just the output for those specific time ranges to "stack" on top of one another. I can run multiple years and turn the opacity down enough where you can see some anomalies, but it turns into a mess after 3+ layers. 

So is there a way to sum just the final outputs of the the '2014' and '2015' layer so it's not summing each data point within the range (and thus giving that red chaos?)

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking there; might be worth starting a new question. Sounds like maybe you're trying to move toward spatial reducers?

Comment: The question is: how would one accumulate the final output of each year's range into one image?

ie taking the final product of 2014 and then stacking it on top of 2015.

Comment: `total2014` in the code above is the sum of all rain in the time window for 2014. Use `Map.addLayer(total2014,{min: 0.0, max: 100.0, palette: ['d8d8d8', '4addff', '5affa3', 'f2ff89', 'ff725c'], "2014"},"2014 summer rain")`.